# Push Notifications for Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, push-notification

I work with desktop application for Windows and I have to add push notification logic, especially receiveng push notification from server. I have read about SignalR and Pushbullet.

- SignalR is good but it supports winforms and starts from Windows 8.
- PushBullet seems to be good but I still read guides.

So, my questions are:

Do other push frameworks(for winforms) exist?
Is it possible to implement receiveng push notification from server to my app?

Comment: FCM? (Firebase Cloud Messaging)

Comment: @zaitsman FCM? How? Via JS? Can you give me a link, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into **WCF** and *Duplex Services*. It can be used to establish a connection between client and server. Here are two links that can help you out.

[MSDN: Duplex Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/duplex-services)

[Example Project for Duplex WCF](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/491844/A-Beginners-Guide-to-Duplex-WCF)

Comment: Thanks! In this case, I need two implementations(server, client), am I right? But is it possible to find some framework/library like OneSignal or something else?

Comment: Yes you need to implement a client and a server, but its not complicated and MSDN has lots of documentation on the subject. Concerning the use of 3rd party frameworks/libraries -- I try to stay away from 3rd party libraries when I can. They are definitely useful and you don't want to re-invent the wheel, but if there's a simple solution without the need for a 3rd party component then IMO its better not to use any 3rd party components.